# Kotlin coroutines: why can't I see logs until the end?

Tags: android, kotlin, kotlin-coroutines

I'm new with kotlin coroutines and have some doubts. So I'm trying to download a list of fonts using a kotlin coroutine, and I added some logs to see when a font is downloaded, or a message when it already existed. I was expecting to see one log each time a font is accessed, however I see only the progressBar, and when it gets hidden, I see all the logs at once. Am I doing something wrong?

```
private fun init() {
    val job = Job()
    val bgScope = CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.IO + job)

    bgScope.launch {
        getStuff()
    }
}

fun getStuff() {
    val uiScope = CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.Main + Job())
    uiScope.launch {
        progressbar.visibility = View.VISIBLE
    }

    for (font in jsonObject.fontList) {
        if (!font.exists()) {
            downloadFile(font)
            Timber.d("file " + font.id + " downloaded: " + font.exists())
        } else {
            Timber.d("file " + font.id + " already exists ")
        }

    }

    uiScope.launch {
        progressbar.visibility = View.GONE
    }
```

Comment: Unsure if this is related to your problem or not, but `launch` starts a job that might run in parallel to the downloading. You might want to use `withContext` instead, so that you can be sure that the progressbar is visible when you start downloading.

Answer (score 0):

That's because your

```
for (font in jsonObject.fontList) {
        if (!font.exists()) {
            downloadFile(font)
            Timber.d("file " + font.id + " downloaded: " + font.exists())
        } else {
            Timber.d("file " + font.id + " already exists ")
        }

    }
```

runs in another thread, and delays the response.Therefore, you should modify you progress visibility after the `downloadFile` has finished.

You should start the coroutine inside your `downloadFileMethod()` along with the progress bar switching on/off.

Comment: But I want the progressBar to be visible during the entire for loop, shouldn't I set it as gone after the loop instead of inside the downloadFile function? In this case, it would be gone after the first font is downloaded it, no?